# On unions and intersections

Tags: set-theory

Let $S$ be a collection of sets. Define $S_\sigma$ to be the collection of arbitrary union of sets in $S$ and $S_\delta$ to be the collection of arbitrary intersections of sets in $S$.

**Is it true that the sets $(S_\sigma)_\delta = (S_\delta)_\sigma$? If not, what is the sufficient condition on $S$ for this to be true?**

It is easy to check that if $S$ is a finite collection of sets, then $S_{\sigma\delta} = S_{\delta\sigma}$ because for finitely many sets union and intersection commutes.

For any arbitrary $S$, it is also easy to verify that $S_\sigma\subset S_{\sigma\delta}$ and $S_\delta\subset S_{\delta\sigma}$.

Comment: What does $S_{\sigma\delta}$ mean? More precisely, is $S_{\sigma\delta}=(S_\sigma)_\delta$ that is are we taking the "delta" of $S_\sigma$?

Comment: @ZeroXLR, Yes $S_{\sigma\delta} = (S_\sigma)_\delta$.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is the general distributive law:
$$
\bigcap_{i\in I}\bigcup_{j\in J_i}A_{i,j}=\bigcup_{f\in F}\bigcap_{i\in I} A_{i,f(i)},
$$
where $F$ is the set of functions $f$, with domain $I$, satisfying $(\forall i\in I)\,f(i)\in J_i$. This gives you that $(S_\sigma)_\delta\subseteq (S_\delta)_\sigma$.  The reverse inclusion follows by considering complements (or equivalently by Boolean duality).

Comment: I used $\sigma$ and $\delta$ as in the question, but it should be noted that these symbols are usually used for countable unions and intersections (for which the analogous interchange rule fails in general); arbitrary unions and intersections are usually denoted by the corresponding capital letters $\Sigma$ and $\Delta$.